# Enable view when RadioButton checked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-radiobutton

I have a `View` (i.e. a `TextInputLayout`, `Button`, whatever) that is disabled but once the `RadioButton` is checked I want to enable that view. And, once the radioButton is unchecked, I want that view to be disabled. I want to do it using `DataBinding`, but it is not working... Help?

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/myself"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/myself"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/group" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/groups_layout"
            style="@style/MyAutoCompleteTextView.Layout.Dense"
            android:enabled="@{group.isChecked()}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the listener of the radio button in your code and accordingly update a liveData, then here in the layout just use `androd:enabled=@{VIEW_MODEL.LIVE_DATA}`

**NOTE :** Make sure that you import the viewModel in the respective layout.